# Problem with admin.js connexion on Heroku and express app (reverse proxy + cookie: secure)

Tags: express, heroku, cookies, reverse-proxy, adminjs

I have an app that runs on Heroku on which the connexion on admin.js does not work anymore:

The problem is that I added dynos in Heroku and Heroku has added a reverse proxy to my app.
On the config for adminjs we use secure cookie and I know the problem come from the interaction of the reverse proxy with the secure cookie.
in the config for Adminjs I use buildAuthenticatedRouter and I have those settings

```
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  proxy: NODE_ENV === 'production',
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: NODE_ENV === 'production',
    secure: NODE_ENV === 'production'
  }
```

in my app.js file I have

```
if (NODE_ENV === 'production') app.enable('trust proxy', true)
```

I thought the   proxy: NODE_ENV === 'production' and app.enable('trust proxy', true) would change something but no it doesn't

Thank you for your help